# Public and temporary files error in my "Status Report"

Tags: 7, files

I just upgraded to 7.25 from 7.19, and now in my Status Report I have a red X on my "Public Files" and "Temporary Files".

> See http://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003 for information about the
>   recommended .htaccess file which should be added to the
>   sites/default/files directory to help protect against arbitrary code
>   execution.

I go to the address above, but I don't have any user friendly explanation of what to do to fix this. Thanks in advance.

### Update: (1/8/14)

The answer below fixes the `Public files` problem 100%.

It does not fix the `Temp files`. To fix temp files, I go to `admin/config/media/file-system` and change the path from `/tmp` to `../tmp`

I will update this if this is fixed in a newer version of drupal, or if there is another fix available. I'm not sure if the `../tmp` is the correct solution, but it works.

Comment: Relevant issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2141065

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest method is in the fine print.  If you haven't edited these files, then

- browse to admin/config/media/file-system
- delete sites/default/files/.htaccess
- delete wherever/your/private/files/are/.htaccess as indicated on the page you just browsed to
- delete wherever/your/tmp/files/are/.htaccess as indicated on the page you just browsed to
- click **SAVE**

This will recreate the two .htaccess files.  Then visit the status report and double check things.

Otherwise, edit sites/default/files/.htaccess to be

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

and wherever/your/private/files/are/.htaccess and wherever/your/tmp/files/are/.htaccess to be

```
Deny from all

# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Note the difference on line 1 for the private files.  This is what prevents files from being browsed to from the outside world.  It is also beneficial to place your private and tmp file directories outside your DOCROOT if you can, as an added precaution.

Comment: Did what you said and it seemed to work like a charm for the public files directory error, but the temporary files directory error still exists. Ideas?

Comment: @EGHDK Make sure the path to the tmp folder is valid

Comment: The path to the temp folder in admin/config/media/file-system says "/tmp". How do I know if it's valid or not?

Comment: @EGHDK Updated for tmp.  If you delete that, too, it will get recreated.

Comment: I don't have any directory "/tmp".

Comment: If I get out of my public_html directory there is a tmp directory. It has different folders like `analog, awstats, cpbandwidth, logaholic, webalizer, webalizerftp` but no .htaccess. I don't remember ever putting anything in this /tmp folder either. I only EVER touch my public_html dir.

Comment: I also suffered from the same issue and while in path (Home » Administration » Configuration » Media » Filesystem) I deleted the names in public/private/tmp, saved the configuration, and then renamed the file paths and all .htacces errors disappeared. Hope that works for ya!

Answer (score 0):

At first Create a folder "tmp" in sites/"default or whatever/files/".
Then Go to Drupal admin "admin/config/file system" and update Temporary path with your tmp directory path.

That's it.